Color range for tty
THIS IS NOT A PROBLEM ABOUT XORG
I have a singleboard PC with Intel N100 with 2 HDMI ports.
When arch boots, the color range changes to limited after i915 takeing over the display from UEFI framebuffer which is always full range.
When I changed display settings in Plasma Wayland session. Full color range will apply to not only the GUI session but also Plymouth and tty.
I want to change the color range when i915 is loaded or use commands to achieve this at startup.
I am working with OLED monitor so grey background caused by limited range is quite a problem for me to test stuffs on tty.
fbset -i output
mode "1920x1080"
    geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : i915drmfb
    Address     : (nil)
    Size        : 8294400
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 1
    YPanStep    : 1
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 7680
    Accelerator : No


Please post your framebuffer configuration found using sudo fbset -i (after i915 is loaded). Note that you may have to install the fbset utility via your distro's package manager (or as a binary)

I added fbset -i output for this

Can you post the same after you change the settings in GUI and return to the VT (TTY), more specifically, the rgba setting

Unfortunately, the output is the same
